# Ubuntu 20.04 launcher icons not changing with icon themes

Tags: icons, launcher

I have the icon theme from https://www.gnome-look.org/s/Gnome/p/1457366 and it changes the icons in Nautilus and various places, but not on the launcher.

How do I change the launcher icons to match a theme rather than changing them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi have downloaded this icon theme and it looks like it's dedicated to kde.
From the fact you cite Nautilus I'm assuming you're using gnome so maybe all the icons for gtk specific apps are missing. For example I was not able to find any firefox icons, just to say